# mod_rewrite with Trailing Slash breaks CSS/IMG/SCRIPTS paths

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make mod_rewrite the first sub-directory string from url in order to create similar functionality as 'jsfiddle.net saved url's within a class/db. The script works fine and does the rewrite.

e.g. of url

```
http://jsfiddle.net/RyEue/
```

This works fine (loads all css, scripts, etc.):

```
http://www.domain.com/787HHJ2
```

This is what I've used in the past which does the trick.

**The problem Is when ending URL with last slash, script, css and others loose path.**

```
http://www.domain.com/787HHJ2/
```

**rewrite script:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
#RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.
RewriteRule ^.+/?$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Unsure if this has to do with Rewritebase, I've tried multiple ways.

PS. I've tried setting paths to absolute (e.g. src="/img/theimage.jpg") without luck.

Comment: The rule is fine. Please turn on rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: @LazyOne, Your right. It works. The issues is that it breaks css, scripts paths.

Comment: I've clarified the question. The problem is mostsly with the css, scripts, images and others been broken upon using the trailing /.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? Try `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`. BTW, what `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.` mean -- only if query string is empty?

Comment: By "breaks" i mean the html elements like img do not load after rewrite. Yes, only is query string is empty. I'm trying to display index.php with all it's elements.

Comment: I'm using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` to detect empty query string. In any case -- if query string is empty the no need for `[QSA]` flag, I guess

Comment: @Codex73 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1766/discussion-between-lazyone-and-codex73)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure you have css/images/js etc linked relative to root folder (with leading slash): `/styles/main.css`

2. Add one of these ruls before current one:

```
# do not touch files with .css/.js/.jpg etc extensions
RewriteRule \.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$ - [L]
```

or

```
# do not touch any resources in images/css/js folders
RewriteRule ^(images|css|js)/ - [L]
```

3. Clear browser caches and restart (sometimes browser may display cached page/resource when rewrite rule was fixed which brings a lot of confusion).

Comment: With the above answer I was able to solve the problem. A combination of relative paths to root plus setting up local virtual hosts allowed everything to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping

```
RewriteRule ^.+\/?$ index.php [QSA,L]
```